# Profiling Pig Query

Tags: apache-pig

I am trying to profile a pig query but haven't got any thing useful so far.

I am trying to measure CPU, disk I/O, RAM usage.

Can anyone guide me on this ?

**Things tried so far**

Starfish - Works with Hadoop job but NOT with Pig 
         - Does not support pig query

Hprof - Works with Hadoop job but NOT with Pig query.
      - Generates profile file only for Hadoop job

Both Hadoop and pig jobs are executed in the same cluster.

Thanks for reading !!

Answer (score 1):

You could get some latency data using JXInsight/Opus (which is free) and marking or tagging the cluster before executing the query and then taking a snapshot following completion of the job.

http://www.jinspired.com/site/jxinsight-opus-1-0

We will be coming out with JXInsight/Opus for X editions for various big data platforms including Cassandra, Hadoop, Pig,....

If you need more power and more meters (cpu, io,...) you can then always look at the JXInsight/OpenCore product.

Comment: William - Thanks a lot for sharing this. It looks like this will do the job. I will try it today and will let you know the results. Again thanks a ton !!

Comment: William, your website does not appear to have any download links :/  I'd love to have tried your product but not being able to download it is a bit of a problem ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can use hprof or other profiling tools on the MR job generated by pig . See https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/PIG/HowToProfile

Comment: Thanks for this information. Earlier I tried Hprof but it generates profile file only for hadoop jobs and not for pig queries. The link provided by you have some other options which looks interesting. I will try it and let you know about the results.

Comment: Thanks a lot user617093. This worked for me. I am unable to vote up this answer because of the point system here. But this works for me. Thanks again !!